# Is weather localized or map-wide?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

How big is a [weather](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Weather) event, such as rain? I'm curious as to whether or not my water resevoirs (located all over the map) get rain-irrigated from every rain storm, but I bet this answer would apply to the behavior of cold, fog, and heat events as well.

Does an event cover the whole map or just a portion? More specifically, are the effects of the weather event simulated even when a player is not "around" to see it (meaning logged in, but not nearby, perhaps across the map)?

Comment: I am not sure whether weather runs when you're not around, though I would strongly lean towards it happening regardless. I do know that weather only covers a portion of the map though. I've been cross map with my friend as it's started raining for me and not for him, and vice versa, and in the swamps it's quite foggy just about everyday and rarely on our northern base is it foggy. Also blizzards only happen in the snow biome, I don't know if they even cover the entirety of it or not. Heat also generally only happens in the more southern/swampy areas. Weather events are definitely localized.